# Airflow no module found error 'airflow.providers.airbyte' on UI

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver, airflow-api, airflow-taskflow

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/dag_airbyte_example.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/dag_airbyte_example.py", line 3, in <module>
    from airflow.providers.airbyte.operators.airbyte import AirbyteTriggerSyncOperator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.airbyte'
```

I have installed all the dependencies and written a script to run my DAGs, but when I try to check on to the UI, I am facing the following issues. The purpose of my task is to run a dag successfully

Comment: could you please share your dependencies in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when I was using the Airflow on localhost in the Astro environment.

What helped me was:

[> Adding the name of a package to the packages.txt or requirements.txt files of your Astro project installs the package to your Airflow environment.](https://docs.astronomer.io/astro/cli/develop-project#:%7E:text=Adding%20the%20name%20of%20a%20package%20to%20the%20packages.txt%20or%20requirements.txt%20files%20of%20your%20Astro%20project%20installs%20the%20package%20to%20your%20Airflow%20environment.)

It became clear to me that **it is not enough** to just add the dependency using `pip install` to the local environment for the Airflow webserver to pick up on the new provider, but instead **it must be added** to the one of the above mentioned .txt files.